# How to handle multiple source files during semantic analysis?

Tags: java, scala, compiler-construction

I'm trying to implement an external DSL using a handcrafted compiler. I'm done with lexing and parsing, however currently I'm lost with regards to resolving symbols from separate files (i.e. inheritance).

I've tried searching for this but nothing comes up relating to the handling on the compiler level. However, I've stumbled upon *object files, linkers and loaders*, but upon further research they seem to play a role after compilation rather than during.

Thank you to anyone who could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is heavily dependent on the nature of your language.

- If you're C-like, you have header files defining the shared symbols, and you #include the header every place it is used (recompiling the header as part of that file).
- If you're Java-like, you have a standard naming convention and package/directory hierarchy to allow you to locate a symbol.
- If you're Javascript-like, you don't resolve any symbols at compile time; you just throw an error if a symbol is not defined when it is used. (For small scripting languages this is often the simplest answer)

If the total amount of code in the DSL is small, a third option is just to load and parse it all and then do the symbol-resolving pass on the whole thing at once.

Comment: In Java if a class is called `MyClass` and it is in `package com.me.mypackage`, then Java looks for the file `[root]/com/me/mypackage/MyClass.class`.